# Как отследить изменение ссылки в адресной строке браузера и удалить атрибут?

Tags: javascript

На странице имеется селектор

```html
<span 
  class="int" 
  onmouseover="infoTooltip.show(this);" 
  onmouseout="infoTooltip.hide(this);"
>
  Текст
</span>
```

Этот код у меня удаляет оба атрибута, но когда открываешь другую страницу сайта, то атрибуты восстанавливаются опять.

```js
$('.int').removeAttr('onmouseover').removeAttr('onmouseout');
```

Как отследить изменение ссылки в адресной строке браузера и удалить атрибуты onmouseover onmouseout? Или хотя бы только onmouseover.

Comment: выполняй свой код на событие [DOMContentLoaded_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: В большинстве случаев, изменение ссылки в адресной строке, это перезагрузка страницы.

Comment: SwaD, сайт не меняется. страница не перезагружается. В строке браузера остается название сайта, но в конце адреса сайта чего-нибудь приписывается.

Comment: *"страница не перезагружается"*  .................. *"когда открываешь другую страницу сайта"*  --- определись, перезагружается или нет

Comment: код в html навсегда можно удалить только на серверной стороне, где этот код генерируется....(ну или разрабами фронта, который этот код написали).... т.е. физически....... ты не можешь физически стереть из файла данные с помощью js кода.

Comment: Алексей, меняется содержимое, а страница не перезагружается. В адресной строке допустим было example.com/game, переходишь на другую страницу example.com/game1 и не какой перезагрузки страницы не происходит.

Comment: Алексей, при загрузке  страницы код работает, удаляет атрибут. Осталось только найти способ отследить изменение адреса в строке и добавить мой код. Но вот как отследить изменение адреса  в строке браузера вот в чём вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Отследить изменение в адресной строке браузера можно так:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
    $('.int').removeAttr('onmouseover').removeAttr('onmouseout');
});
```

Comment: в js есть такое событие как locationchange?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Мда, что то не вставил. Поправил

Comment: SwaD, у меня этот код не работает. Если ещё какие способы?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", remAttr, false);
function remAttr() {
document.querySelector(".int").removeAttribute("onmouseover"); }
```

У меня работает этот код. Удаляет атрибут и при обновлении страницы и при переходе по страницам сайта.